Not to show/hide values in second slicer based on first Slicer
How can we hide values which are less than in second slicer based on selected value in first slicer
Ex: If user select value 6 in first slicer then in second slicer values need to apper only >=6   (i.e 6,7,8,9,10,11,12) , remaining values from 1-5 should be hide or make user not able to click.
Both slicers are coming from 2 different tables
First Slicer values from 1 to 12
Second slicer Values from 1 to 12.
Slicer-1

Slicer-2

Thanks in advance.

you can try this
create measure
Measure = if(max('Table 2'[Month])>=SELECTEDVALUE('Table 1'[Month]),1,0)
add the measure to visual filter and set to 1

